# Magento 2: Disable search function catalogsearch/result

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, advanced-search

Does anyone know about way to disable any request like this

```
http://site.lo/catalogsearch/result/?q=flower
```

just don't need implement any request for that.

please do not suggest disable magento-search or magento-advanced-search modules.

Many Thanks for any advance on that.

Comment: You have to disable search text only `flower`?

Comment: I need to disable search totally